# Mongoose Aggregate Query Issue: Filtering Objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working on a Mongoose aggregate query to filter objects within an array based on a specific condition, but I'm facing some difficulties. I'm using "mongoose" v7.5.0. Specifically, I want to filter objects within an array based on the presence of a key called "isIgnoredUntil." If the "isIgnoredUntil" key exists and is not set to null or an empty string, I want to include the object; otherwise, I want to exclude it. At the moment, my query either filters the entire case where the key exists or doesn't filter at all.

The case schema is embedded within a customer schema and has the following structure:

```
[
    {
        "caseId": "98765",
        "protocols": [
            {
                "_id": "6532454d4fab6bf644091c47"
            },
            {
                "_id": "6532454d4fab6bf644091c48"
            }
        ],
        "reports": [
            {
                "eqis": [
                    {
                        "protocoled": false,
                        "urgency": 0,
                        "_id": "6532454d4fab6bf644091c4a",
                        "isIgnoredUntil": "2023-12-01T12:12:12.000Z"
                    },
                    {
                        "protocoled": false,
                        "urgency": 0,
                        "_id": "6532454d4fab6bf644091c5a"
                    }
                ],
                "_id": "6532454d4fab6bf644091c49"
            }
        ],
        "_id": "6532454d4fab6bf644091c46"
    }
]
```

And here's my current Mongoose aggregate query:

```
const cases = await Customer.aggregate([
  { $unwind: '$cases' },
  { $match: { 'cases.assignedToUserId': new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userid) } },
  { $unwind: '$cases.reports' },
  { $unwind: '$cases.reports.eqis' },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$cases.caseId',
      eqis: { $push: '$cases.reports.eqis' },
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      caseId: '$_id',
      eqis: {
        $filter: {
          input: '$eqis',
          as: 'eqi',
          cond: {
            $and: [
              {
                $or: [
                  { $eq: ['$$eqi.urgency', { $min: '$eqis.urgency' }] },
                  { $eq: ['$$eqi.isIgnoredUntil', null] },
                ],
              },
              {
                $lt: ['$$eqi.isIgnoredUntil', new Date()],
              },
            ],
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  // Filter out cases with empty eqis array
  {
    $match: {
      eqis: { $not: { $size: 0 } },
    },
  },
  // sort urgency and caseId (asc)
  {
    $sort: {
      'eqis.urgency': 1,
      'cases.caseId': 1,
    },
  },
]);
```

I need help restructuring my query so that I can filter objects within the "eqis" array based on the presence and value of the "isIgnoredUntil" key. Thank you!

UPDATE: I have revised my mongoose query, and the logic appears somewhat unconventional to me. I am uncertain as to why it is functioning as expected. This is because I need to apply a similar filtering approach to another key, just like I do for "isIgnoredUntil." However, when I add an additional condition, it either returns nothing or includes all items again.

Answer (score 1):

Can you just try with this query,

```
const cases = await Customer.aggregate([
  { $unwind: '$cases' },
  { $match: { 'cases.assignedToUserId': new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userid) } },
  { $unwind: '$cases.reports' },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$cases.caseId',
      eqis: { $push: '$cases.reports.eqis' },
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      caseId: '$_id',
      eqis: {
        $map: {
          input: {
            $filter: {
              input: '$eqis',
              as: 'eqi',
              cond: {
                $and: [
                  { $eq: ['$$eqi.urgency', { $min: '$eqis.urgency' }] },
                  { $cond: { if: '$$eqi.isIgnoredUntil', then: true, else: false } }
                ]
              },
            },
          },
          as: 'filtered',
          in: {
            protocoled: '$$filtered.protocoled',
            urgency: '$$filtered.urgency',
            _id: '$$filtered._id',
            isIgnoredUntil: '$$filtered.isIgnoredUntil'
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: '$eqis'
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      'eqis.urgency': 1,
    },
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$caseId',
      eqis: { $push: '$eqis' },
    },
  },
]);
```

If it will not work then let's take another option. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, your query returns an empty array.